# How to create association Sequelize Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

I want to create an association so that when Doctor's data is fetched it should also fetch the data of the specialization using the id of specialization.

**Doctor Model**

```
export class Doctor extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public user_id: number;
  public specialization_id: string;
  public readonly created_at!: Date;
  public readonly updated_at!: Date;
  public readonly deleted_at!: Date;
}
Doctor.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    user_id: {
      type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      references: {
        model: "User",
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    specialization_id: {
      type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      references: {
        model: "Specialization",
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    created_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
    updated_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
    deleted_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
  },
  {
    tableName: "Doctor",
    sequelize,
    paranoid: true,
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at",
    deletedAt: "deleted_at",
  }
);
```

**Specialization Model**

```
export class Specialization extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public name: string;
    public readonly created_at!: Date;
    public readonly updated_at!: Date;
    public readonly deleted_at!: Date;
}
Specialization.init(
    { 
    id: {
        type: new DataTypes.INTEGER(),
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: new DataTypes.STRING(),
    },
        created_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
        updated_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
        deleted_at: new DataTypes.DATE(),
    },
    {
        tableName: "Specialization",
        sequelize,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        deletedAt: "deleted_at",
    }
);
```

I am fetching data by creating associations in Specialization model but it  is not working.

```
export class Specialization extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public name: string;
    public readonly created_at!: Date;
    public readonly updated_at!: Date;
    public readonly deleted_at!: Date;

    static associate(model) {
        Specialization.hasMany(Doctor, { as: 'doctor', foreignKey: 'specialization_id'});
        Doctor.belongsTo(Specialization, { as: 'specialization', foreignKey: 'specialization_id'});
    }
}
```

and fetching it like this

```
 try {
      return await Doctor.findAll({
         include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]
      });
 } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e)
 }
```

response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "specialization_id": 1,
        "fees": 1000,
        "experience": 5,
        "education": "MBBS",
        "about": null,
        "created_at": "2022-10-19T13:30:08.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-19T13:30:08.000Z",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 3,
        "specialization_id": 2,
        "fees": 1500,
        "experience": 5,
        "education": "MBBS",
        "about": null,
        "created_at": "2022-10-19T13:30:08.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-19T13:30:08.000Z",
        "deleted_at": null
    }
]
```

Comment: When I try to change include: [{ all: true, nested: true }] to include: [Specialization] it gives this Error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Specialization is not associated to Doctor!